# How to update Scene 1 data view when I am in scene 2 view in JavaFx?

Tags: java, exception, javafx, nullpointerexception

The problem I am facing is I am trying to fetch the data through excel file and inserting it into my database and after that the data on the table should be updated but it is not happening.

here is my main class which causes to open a new frame through which I can upload the excel data and insert it into my database.

`AddNewAccountHolderController.java` file.

```
@FXML
void onImport() {
    ImportAccountHoldersData accountHolder = new ImportAccountHoldersData();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    try {
        accountHolder.start(stage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

This function opens up a new view and its controller is `ImportAccountHoldersDataController.java`. Now in this controller I have a insert function that inserts the data into the database.

here is the function:

```
@FXML
void onInsert() {
    try {
        // Check if the table is not empty
        if (accountHoldersTableView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            MessageDialogs.showErrorMessage("No account holders to insert.");
            return; // Exit the method since there's nothing to insert
        }

        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        CallableStatement statement = db.connection.prepareCall("{CALL sp_create_account_holder(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");

        boolean allRecordsInserted = true;

        for (AccountHolder accountHolder : accountHoldersTableView.getItems()) {
            // Set the input parameters for the stored procedure
            statement.setString(1, accountHolder.getName());
            String cnicNo = accountHolder.getCnicNo().replaceAll("-", "");
            statement.setBigDecimal(2, BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(cnicNo)));
            statement.setString(3, accountHolder.getAddress());
            statement.setString(4, accountHolder.getPhone());
            statement.setBoolean(5, accountHolder.isisRetailer());

            statement.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);

            // Execute the stored procedure
            statement.execute();

            // Retrieve the result message
            String resultMessage = statement.getString(6);

            if (!resultMessage.equals("Account holder added successfully.")) {
                allRecordsInserted = false;
            }
        }

        // Close the database connection and statement
        db.connection.close();
        statement.close();

        if (allRecordsInserted) {
            MessageDialogs.showMessageDialog("All account holders created successfully.");

                AddNewAccountHolderController controller = new AddNewAccountHolderController();
controller.populateAccountHoldersTable();


        } else {
            MessageDialogs.showErrorMessage("Error inserting account holder(s).");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the exception for debugging purposes
        log.error("Error inserting account holders(s): " + e.getMessage(), e);

        // Show a user-friendly error message
        MessageDialogs.showErrorMessage("An error occurred while inserting account holder(s).");
    }
}
```

Now as you can see after successful insertion of all records. I want to update the table view of the previous view called `AddNewAccountHolderController.java` file’s view. But this is giving me a null pointer exception.

```
ERROR com.al_makkah_traders_app.controller.ImportAccountHoldersDataController - Error inserting account holders(s): Cannot invoke "com.al_makkah_traders_app.controller.AddNewAccountHolderController.populateAccountHoldersTable()" because "this.addNewAccountHolderController" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.al_makkah_traders_app.controller.AddNewAccountHolderController.populateAccountHoldersTable()" because "this.addNewAccountHolderController" is null
```

I don’t know how to prevent it and update table view.

Comment: This is simply the wrong approach.  One controller should not call another controller (especially an instance that you create yourself rather than an instance from FXML).  Apply an [MVC approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx) instead.  Place the data in the observable list backing the table in a model and update that list.

Answer (score 0):

**In the controller of your new Stage:**

Add an attribute of class Runnable with the name "callbackOnClose".
Create a setter for this attribute.
At the end of "onInsert" execute "callbackOnClose.run()".

**In the parent Stage:**

Before loading the new Stage/Scene, get the controller of it and set the callback with the setter method you created.
You can create a Runnable and pass it as parameter or do it with a Lambda.
Because you are in the parent views controller, you can access its attributes.

**Note:**

This is the way I do it in all of my projects and it worked every time like a charm.

**Note 2:**

You can use any type of Interface instead of Runnable. You can create your own Interface if you need to.